# How to remove Take() function from linq query when index is -1?

Tags: c#, linq

I am using Take() function with linq query. But I want to remove Take() function from linq query if I give Take(-1) in it. Because I don't want make sql query with "Top" clause if index is -1.

Thanks in advance for suggestion.

Comment: The query returns lac of records and the query is become slow and sometime I am giving index >1 and sometime I require all records then I give index no -1. So I don't want Take function in case of all records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for suggestion but I got the answer. I made a extension method and checked the index there. This is the extension method which I used.

```
public static IQueryable<T> SkipTakeQuery<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, int skipIndex, int takeIndex)
        {
            if (skipIndex == -1)
            {
                return query;
            }
            return query.Skip(skipIndex).Take(takeIndex);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var itemsToTake = -1;
IQueryable<T> data = your items collection with any linq you want;

// Apply Take method, if required
if (itemsToTake > 0)
    data = data.Take(itemsToTake);

// continue using data: return it or convert to list, etc
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but when I execute linq query it gives lac of records and it takes time to execute without Take. Only I wanna remove Take() when I wanna take all records by linq.

Comment: @Deepak Isn't this what Kamarey is suggesting based on your question? You said -1 means you are taking all records. So in his answer it will not append the Take to the query if the variable is -1. Otherwise it will use Take. So you just need to set the itemsToTake variable according to how many items you really want to take (i.e. set it equal to your index).

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but I got the answer. I made a extension method and checked the index there. This is the extension method which I used.                                                      public static IQueryable<T> SkipTakeQuery<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, int skipIndex, int takeIndex)
        {
            if (skipIndex == -1)
            {
                return query;
            }
            return query.Skip(skipIndex).Take(takeIndex);
        }